# The Active Directory App created using Visual Studio does not have any "Certificate & Secrets".. is this fine?

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-identity-platform

I created a new ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC web application, and I define it to use Azure AD for authentication, as follows:

[image]

[image]

Then I was asked to create an owned application, so I created one named "ad" as follows:

[image]

[image]

Inside my application's `appsetting.json` I have these settings:

```
{
    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Domain": "*****",
        "TenantId": "***",
        "ClientId": "***",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    },
    ....
}
```

It seems Visual Studio did all the work for us.

But when I checked the "Certificate & Secrets" in the Azure portal, I found that there is not anything assigned:

[image: ![enter image description here](/api/attachments/b6569579-d324-43c7-86a0-ff57ce1783ca?platform=QnA)]

So for the purpose to authenticate users inside my ASP.NET Core MVC web application, do we need to add "Certificate" or "Secrets"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you only want to integrate Azure AD to make your users sign in your application with their microsoft account, no need to use Client secret here**. You can see [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#add-credentials):

> Credentials are used by confidential client applications that access a
> web API

The API can be Microsoft graph API or your custom AP, I trust you will see this step when you connect your application to Azure identity platform in Visual Studio, this is the API:

[image]

If you pick up Graph API option, then you will see this step:

[image]

And this time, it will create Client Secret for you in Azure AD portal.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply .. so if i want to authenticate users from my asp.net core mvc web application using Microsoft Identity platform i do not have to add any secret or certificate to the related Azure Ad APP?

Comment: yes, if you only want to auth users , no need to use client secret. the document mentioned it. And I also test it in my side, no secret can still make the app work well, I mean I can sign in the application with my microsoft accunt

Comment: yes i know that it will work.. but is this a secure approach? as in this case (if i do not specify any client secret or certificat) my Azure Active Directory app can be called by anonymous users? am i correct?

Comment: this is a secure approach. Your app, I mean if you just use the template the create the project and integrate AAD, the `HomeController` will be added `[Authorize]` which makes users must sign in first to visit your view. It's not related to client secret.

Comment: By the way, not using client secret doesn't mean not secure, after doing all the operations, you can use your microsoft account to sign in your app, but I can't use my microsoft account to sign in your app. that's because the azure ad app id you used in your application is created in your tenant, since I'm not in your tenant, so I can't sign in your app. your app will only allow users in your tenant to sign in.

Comment: totally understood... but if we look at security into layers then defining a client secret will be a good appraoch to follow.. atleast we will be sure that our Azure AD APP is not been called by anonymous users.. but i am not sure how i can pass the client secret from my aspnet core mvc web application to the Azure Ad APP?

Comment: I answered it in your another case ...

Answer (score 1):

> But when I checked the "Certificate & Secrets" in the Azure portal, I found that there is not anything assigned:

Initially I have added the `Microsoft Identity Platform` by selecting the `Authentication type` from the Template (same like what you have shown in Screenshot).

[image]

- Publish the Application to `Azure App Service`.
- First even I am unable to find the secrets  under `Certificate & Secrets` in AAD.

[image]

- To get the `Certificates & Secrets` in `Azure Active Directory`, we need to connect the `Microsoft Identity platform`  under `Service Dependencies` from the `Publish` window.

[image]

- Click on `Connect`and continue with the Next steps.
- Now check in the `Active Directory` => `App Registrations`, you can see the `Client secret` is added.

[image]

[image]

- Another option to add `Microsoft Identity platform` is, Instead of selecting the `Authentication type` in the template add directly from the `Connected Services`.

[image]

Comment: but based on Tiny Wang reply, that "When you only want to integrate Azure AD to make your users sign in your application with their microsoft account, no need to use Client secret here. You can see this section:"... any advice?

Comment: Yes, I do agree with that point. I have addressed the point, where you have missed the `Certificates & Secrets` even after adding the `Microsoft Identity Platform`.